# Dynamic pivot without aggregation

Tags: sql-server

Hi i have seen a lot of articles but none of them replies to my question.
i have a table ProductPropertyPrice

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Product_PropertyPrice](
[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[ProductID] [int] NULL,
[PropertyID] [int] NULL,
[PropertyValueID] [int] NULL,
[PriceID] [int] NULL,
[ValidFrom] [date] NULL,
```

and i want to have a row for every product and each valid from date with all the properties id and propertiesvaluesid and price id as columns

i tried this but is not working can anybody help me?

sorry i can not post my code , i am getting an error and i am new in the stachoverflow

```
     create PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetPriceTable] (@ProductTypeID  int)
       AS
    BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.PropertyID) 
            FROM (SELECT Product_PropertiesLookup.PropertyID,Product_PropertiesLookup.PropertyName
FROM         Product_PropertiesLookup INNER JOIN
                      Product_PropertiesperProductType ON Product_PropertiesLookup.PropertyID = Product_PropertiesperProductType.ProductPropertyID
WHERE     (Product_PropertiesperProductType.ProductTypeID = 1)) c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

        --pivot query 
set @query = 'SELECT  ProductID,PriceID,ValidFrom, ' + @cols + ',rownum from 
            ( SELECT     ProductID, PriceID, ValidFrom,PropertyValueID,PropertyID,
            row_number() over (partition by  propertyid order by productid ) as RowNum
      FROM         Product_PropertyPrice ) x
            pivot 
            (
              max(PropertyValueID)
                for PropertyID in (' + @cols + ')

            ) p '
           exec (@query)
       END
```

i am getting this results

```
ProductID   PriceID     ValidFrom  1           2           3           4           RowNum
----------- ----------- ---------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- --------------------
110         1           2015-01-01 0           NULL        1           1           1
110         1           2015-01-01 NULL        NULL        NULL        1           2
110         1           2015-01-01 NULL        NULL        1           1           3
110         1           2015-01-01 1           NULL        1           1           4
110         1           2015-01-01 2           NULL        NULL        1           5
110         1           2015-01-01 NULL        NULL        NULL        1           6
110         1           2015-01-01 NULL        NULL        NULL        1           7
110         1           2015-01-01 3           NULL        NULL        1           8
110         1           2015-01-01 4           NULL        1           1           9
110         1           2015-01-01 NULL        NULL        1           1           10
110         1           2015-01-01 5           NULL        1           1           11
110         1           2015-01-01 6           NULL        1           1           12
110         1           2015-01-01 7           NULL        1           1           13
110         1           2015-01-01 8           NULL        1           1           14
110         1           2015-01-01 9           NULL        1           1           15
110         1           2015-01-01 10          NULL        1           1           16
110         1           2015-01-01 11          NULL        1           1           17
110         1           2015-01-01 12          NULL        1           1           18
110         1           2015-01-01 13          NULL        1           1           19
110         1           2015-01-01 14          NULL        1           1           20
110         1           2015-01-01 15          NULL        1           1           21
110         1           2015-01-01 16          NULL        1           1           22
110         1           2015-01-01 17          NULL        1           1           23
110         1           2015-01-01 NULL        NULL        1           1           24
110         1           2015-01-01 NULL        NULL        1           1           25
110         1           2015-01-01 NULL        NULL        1           1           26
110         1           2015-01-01 NULL        NULL        1           1           27
110         1           2015-01-01 NULL        NULL        1           1           28
110         1           2015-01-01 NULL        NULL        1           1           29

sample data

id          ProductID   PropertyID  PropertyValueID PriceID     ValidFrom
----------- ----------- ----------- --------------- ----------- ----------
70          110         1           23              2           2015-01-01
71          110         3           1               2           2015-01-01
72          110         4           1               2           2015-01-01
73          110         1           24              2           2015-01-01
74          110         3           1               2           2015-01-01
75          110         4           1               2           2015-01-01
76          110         1           25              3           2015-01-01
77          110         3           1               3           2015-01-01
78          110         4           1               3           2015-01-01
79          110         1           26              3           2015-01-01
80          110         3           1               3           2015-01-01
81          110         4           1               3           2015-01-01
82          110         1           27              3           2015-01-01
83          110         3           1               3           2015-01-01
84          110         4           1               3           2015-01-01

Result i need
 ProductID   PropertyID(1)  PropertyID(3) PropertyID(4) PriceID     ValidFrom
  110         23            1              1            2           2015-01-01
  110         24            1              1            2           2015-01-01
  110         25            1              1            3           2015-01-01
  110         26            1              1            3           2015-01-01
  110         27            1              1            3           2015-01-01
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You wrote you get an error, what is the error you get?

Comment: hi. i amor not getting the data the way i need. they are grouped in not a normal way. do you want me to send you my input data?

Comment: i am getting this result

Comment: @Yannis - share some sample data and expected output

Comment: Thanks @Indian. i just did. please let me know if you need any other clarification

Comment: thats enough go write answer.  came to bed will post an asnwer tomorrow

Comment: Hi @Indian, do you have the time to show me the solution please?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
SELECT ProductID,
       [PropertyID(1)]=Max([PropertyID(1)]),
       [PropertyID(3)]=Max([PropertyID(3)]),
       [PropertyID(4)]=Max([PropertyID(4)]),
       ValidFrom=Max(ValidFrom)
FROM   (SELECT ProductID,
               rn=Row_number()
                    OVER(
                      partition BY PropertyID
                      ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)),
               PropertyID,
               CASE WHEN PropertyID = 1 THEN PropertyValueID END   AS [PropertyID(1)],
               CASE WHEN PropertyID = 3 THEN PropertyValueID END   AS [PropertyID(3)],
               CASE WHEN PropertyID = 4 THEN PropertyValueID END   AS [PropertyID(4)],
               PriceID,
               ValidFrom AS ValidFrom
        FROM   Yourtable)a
GROUP  BY ProductID,
          rn
```

You need to convert the above to `dynamic query`. Please tell me if you need any help in converting to `dynamic query`

Comment: Thanks @Indian. i would be grateful if you can convert it to dynamic and if possible can we do that as a Table function because i need to query to results? Thanks in advance

Comment: Wait please before you create it it seems it is not returning correct results. let me check it a bit and send you some feedback

Comment: i successfully added the price id as a column . the only problem is that you query displayed the first rows with null values. All other rows are correctly displayed

Comment: Dear @Indian i checked i find out that the query creates 5 wrong rows in the beginning with the property3 as null and it adds 5 more rows in the end with property 3 not null and other properties null

Comment: screenshots:https://www.dropbox.com/s/r517kr0fuj4wx7g/Screenshot%202015-08-03%2013.51.11.png?dl=0

Comment: screenshot from bottom results https://www.dropbox.com/s/d8t3f7plbuujszb/Screenshot%202015-08-03%2013.51.23.png?dl=0

Comment: Hi @indian, did you had the time to realise the problem?

Comment: hi @Indian , can you please help me with the solution. do you have time to do so?